# Regular expression to detect a dot at the start or the end

Tags: java, regex

So I have a need to detect that a username is in the format `firstname.lastname`
It cannot have dots at the beginning or the end so it cannot have spaces either. Im using Perl5Util matcher to match the strings in Java.

What is the best way to do this in regular expression ?

I used `[A-Za-z0-9\\.]` but unfortunately this detects dots at the beginning and end.

```
private static final String ALPHANUMERIC = "[A-Za-z0-9\\.]";
private static final String USERNAME_PATTERN = "/^" + ALPHANUMERIC + "+$/";

public static boolean isValidUsername(final String username) {
    final Perl5Util userMatcher = new Perl5Util();
    return userMatcher.match(USERNAME_PATTERN, username);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect a dot at the start or the end you can use a regex like this:

```
^\.|\.$
```

However, you can also use below regex to match string having dots in the middle:

```
^\w+(\.?\w+)*$
```

Using this you can have multiple dots in the middle like `some.thing.too`

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eV2nR2/1)**

[image]

In case that you only want to check for `some.thing` format, when you can use this:

```
^\w+\.?\w+$
```

Bear in mind that `\w` is the shortcut for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, so if you want to get rid of `_`, you can change it to:

```
(?i)^[a-z]+\.?[a-z]+$
 ^-- insensitive flag
```

Comment: Would the pipe symbol cause this to allow `.foo` since it matches the second alternative?

Comment: This answers the question title, but not the actual question.

Comment: brilliant. this works. i changed this slightly to only allow alphanumeric.
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$

Comment: I tried ^\w+\.?\w+$ on firstnamelastname but it seems to parse it. any idea why ?

Comment: Got it by doing ^(\w+)\.{1}(\w+)$

Comment: @nixgadgets if you use \w in java remember to escape the backslash within the string with `\\w`

Answer (score 2):

You could match on

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Comment: Thanks that works. If i want to match another format say firstnamelastname I tried ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9])+$
but that doesnt really work when its .firstnamelastname. Anyway around this ?

Comment: are you saying that you _do_ want `.` at the beginning now?

Comment: no what i mean is no dot in the middle. But it should invalidate if there is a dot at the beginning or the end still.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return username.matches("[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9.]*[A-Za-z0-9]");
```

No need to escape dot in character class.